# Textfield not working properly inside a table ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, use-state

I have an object containing an array of objects

```
initialPreconfigTodoState = { 
todos: [
{
  title: 'title1',
  dueDate: new Date(),
  create: true,
  assignedTo: 'role',
},
{
  title: 'title2',
  dueDate: new Date(),
  create: true,
  assignedTo: 'role',
}]
};
```

I use this array of object to control the state of a Textfield in a table

```
const [preconfig, setPreconfig] = useState(initialPreconfigTodoState);
 


{preconfig.todos.map((todo, index) => {
                  return (
                    <TableRow
                      className="h-64 cursor-pointer"
                      key={Math.random()}
                    >
                      <TableCell className="th" component="th" scope="row">
                        <TextField
                          id={`titleForm${index}`}
                          name={`titleForm${index}`}
                          onChange={(event) => handleTitle(event, index)}
                          value={todo.title}
                          type="text"
                          variant="outlined"
                          required={todo.create ? true : false}
                          fullWidth
                        />
                      </TableCell>
```

when I try to type in the Textfield I don't know what happens but I need to click the Textfield for every character I type, I think is the useState hook that is causing this problem when re-rendering the component and I can't find a solution for this.

this is my handle function on the onChange Callback,

```
const handleTitle = (event, index) => {
let newArray = [...preconfig.todos];
newArray[index] = {
  ...newArray[index],
  title: event.target.value,
};
setPreconfig({ todos: newArray });
```

};

here is the full code

```
const initialPreconfigTodoState = {
todos: [
{
  title: "title1",
  dueDate: new Date(),
  create: true,
  assignedTo: "Role"
},
{
  title: "title2",
  dueDate: new Date(),
  create: true,
  assignedTo: "Role"
}
]
};
function TodoDialog() {
 const [preconfig, setPreconfig] = 
 useState(initialPreconfigTodoState);

 const handleTitle = (event, index) => {
  let newArray = [...preconfig.todos];
  newArray[index] = {
  ...newArray[index],
  title: event.target.value
 };
 setPreconfig({ todos: newArray });
};

return (
<div>
  <Dialog open={true} maxWidth="xl" scroll="paper">
    <DialogContent>
      <div>
        <Table aria-labelledby="tableTitle">
          <TableBody>
            <TableRow className="h-64 cursor-pointer" key=. 
              {Math.random()}>
              <TableCell className="th" component="th" scope="row">
                Title
              </TableCell>

              <TableCell className="th" component="th" scope="row">
                Due Date
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell className="th" component="th" scope="row">
                Asigned To
              </TableCell>

              <TableCell className="th" component="th" scope="row">
                Create
              </TableCell>
            </TableRow>

            {preconfig.todos.map((todo, index) => {
              return (
                <TableRow
                  className="h-64 cursor-pointer"
                  key={Math.random()}
                >
                  <TableCell className="th" component="th" scope="row">
                    <TextField
                      id={`titleForm${index}`}
                      name={`titleForm${index}`}
                      onChange={(event) => handleTitle(event, index)}
                      value={todo.title}
                      type="text"
                      variant="outlined"
                      required={todo.create ? true : false}
                      fullWidth
                    />
                  </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              );
            })}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    </DialogContent>
    <DialogActions>
      <Button color="primary" variant="contained">
        Cancel
      </Button>
      <Button type="submit" color="primary" variant="contained" autoFocus>
        Save
      </Button>
    </DialogActions>
  </Dialog>
</div>
  );
}
```

Comment: did you try using event.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation(); in handleTitle function ?

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, I tried but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `key={Math.random()}` on TableRow.

Change it to `key={index}` and it should work.

With the `Math.random()` your keys changes every rendering and react loses its reference.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by then`useState` indeed. Your whole form (I suppose it's a form of some kind) changes the array from which it's mapped in `render`. No wonder the whole form re-renders.

The obvious solution would be to store the input values (eg in state) and update the original array (via `setPreconfig`) only on submit.